# Probability question regarding independence of events

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

The question was posed in this way:

> Suppose John and Jan read a book separately. Each person has a probability of $.5$ to catch a typo and the each event to catch a typo is independent. Let $A = T_1, T_2, T_3$ caught by John, and $B = T_1, T_2, T_3$ caught by Jan where $T_i$ denotes typo $i$ is caught. Are A and B independent events?

I interpreted this as a multionimial distribution assuming there exists only one book, so the events are not independent. I thought the probability function would look something like this for event A:
$$p(T_{{1}_{John}} = 1, T_{{2}_{John}} = 1, T_{{3}_{John}} = 1, T_{{1}_{Jan}} = 0,  T_{{2}_{Jan}} = 0, T_{{3}_{Jan}} = 0).$$

Since there is only one book, I thought of this as similar to two people flipping the same coin. However, this answer was marked incorrect. The correct answer was the events are independent, but I am still confused as to why this approach is incorrect.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: The events are independent because Jan's have caught (or not caught) any particular or group of typos has no bearing on John's having caught that or any other typo.  p(A=1,1,1)=0.125 (i.e. 1/8) whether B=0,0,0; 0,0,1; 0,1,0; 0,1,1; 1,0,0; etc....  p(A=0,0,1)=0.125 (i.e. 1/8) whether B=0,0,0; etc..

Comment: How can Jan and John both be reading the same book if they read it seperately? I see this as 2 people flipping 1 coin at 2 different places at the same time. This puts extra assumptions on the hypothesis the way I see it. This is where I see the dependence lies in the book they must read to catch the typos.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the book doesn't force a dependence among the events.